# Memory Leak in very small method (objective-c/iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Problem with some very small method inside my iPhone application.

The sample code (similar to the real code):

```
+ (void) drawSomething: (UIView *) theView anImportantNumber: (NSNumber *) importantNumber {
    UIImage *tehImage = [[WebviewUtil sharedInstance] goldStarImage];

    int iCount = 0;
    double roundedNumber = round([importantNumber doubleValue]);
    for (; iCount <= (4 - roundedNumber); iCount++) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((iCount * 15) + 9, 6, 14, 13)];
        [imageView setImage:tehImage];
        [imageView setOpaque:YES];
        [theView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
}
```

In the Line `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake` the Instruments reports an memory leak.  Can anyone give me a hint, what the mistake is? I thought, the `[imageView release];` would do it ?!

Many thanks, if anyone can help me :))

Comment: In the simulator or in a real device? (The simulator sometimes gives false readings - always test on a real device)

Comment: Can you add the code for `[[WebviewUtil sharedInstance] goldStarImage]` - the leak might be in there

Comment: (Are you using the "compile and analyze" operation to get that warning?)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Instruments to detect leaks, take into account the fact the leaks will show you the point where the leaked memory is allocated, not the point where the leak actually happens.

Your code seems right to me. You correctly release `imageView` after adding it as a subview. The problem might lay with `theView` or any other object containing it. So you can review that part in your code (e.g., is `theView` correctly released?)

Answer (score 0):

have u used imageNamed: method? because this method causes memory leak in imageView :)

Comment: check this :http://losingfight.com/blog/2009/09/14/uiimage-imagenamed-is-a-memory-leak-but-only-on-2-x/

Answer (score 0):

try to keep break point at for (; iCount <= (4 - roundedNumber); iCount++)
and see to it that at any point 4-roundedNumber does not go out of range or having some unusual value that it should not have...